# How to get Cube Data Source View Last Schema Update value

Tags: c#, ssas, cube, xmla, dmv

SQL Server Analysis Services

Is there a way to get the **data source view last schema update** value as seen on the properties dialog box?

If I use the DMV syntax:

SELECT * FROM $System.MDSCHEMA_CUBES

It will list all the measures and dimensions used in the cube database which shows details the same as right clicking the measure or dimension and selecting properties. But, this query does not include the properties for data source or data source view.

Thanks in advance!

Regards and Thanks,

Willie P

P.S. The main reason why I need to get the Last Schema Update for data source view, measures and dimension is to determine if a particular cube element was customized/modified by the client so that if we have to deploy an update to the cube, we have an option to update a particular cube element or not just by getting the Last Schema Update.

If this is not possible using SSAS DMV's, maybe a C# sample program will do.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything in the SSAS DMVs to tell you if source data has changed. I don't think there is necessarily anything in SQL Server that would tell you when a table or view was last changed unless they are explicitly capturing changes or auditing DDL statements.

Comment: Hi mmarie, thanks for the comment. If there is no SSAS DMV's to tell me if the data source view schema was changed, is there any other to get this value? I'm using c# for this project, is there a way here instead? Thanks again. :)